# css align text in front of image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have an image and a text in front of it. the problem is, I cant align text and image, text is always in the bottom and I want it in the middle-front of image.

here is the problem:

```css
    .imgf{
     width:45px;
    }
    .textf{
     margin-left:2px;
    }
```

```html
<img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Nuvola_wikipedia_icon.png/240px-Nuvola_wikipedia_icon.png class=imgf> <span class=textf>comments(20)</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is to add

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to the style of .imgf

```css
.imgf {
  width:45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.textf {
  margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Nuvola_wikipedia_icon.png/240px-Nuvola_wikipedia_icon.png class=imgf> <span class=textf>comments(20)</span>
```

The reason you are getting this issue is because by default, images are aligned to the *baseline*, so inorder to vertically align it to the center we use `vertical-align` property with a value of `middle`.

Comment: @MrAlien Bhai ! nice solution but ..... one question is the img being aligned to the span or the span is being aligned to the img ??

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Let me explain you this way, draw a line below your text, that's a base line, by default your image base touches to the baseline, inorder to over ride that behavior you use middle where the image is pushed half below that baseline

Comment: @MrAlien Wow thanks so basically its the image moving right , not the span ?

Comment: Think that's the point of perspective, since baseline was at bottom - you can say baseline moved up (from the point of block position). But if you watch from the baseline: than yes, the image moved down and text remained on line.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik yap, its the image what moves and not the text

Answer (score 1):

```
.imgf{
 width:45px;
    float:left;
}
.textf{
 margin-left:2px;
}
```

This would do the trick :)

Comment: It does not do it: [text is aligned to top of the image](http://jsfiddle.net/3gvezL9t/5/)

Answer (score 1):

The `img` element's bottom will be located at the same line with the text's baseline. So you can change the `img`'s `vertical-align` like this:

```
img {
    vertical-align: -18px;
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3gvezL9t/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example

I would put the image in a container , make the container position relative and everything thats insite with position absolute, so you can position it freely.

I know this might be a bit over the top for YOUR SPECIFIC case, but in general that would help you with aligning anything

Look at my example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEwQdB

```
<style>
div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:green;
}
div img{
  background-color:red;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-90px;
  margin-top:-90px;
  top:50%;
}
div span{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
</style>
<div>
  <img src="#"/>
  <span>title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in html code as folow:

```
<div id="imag">
  you text here
 </div>
```

css code as follow:

```
#imag
{
  background-image:imagepath/image_name.jpg;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
}
```