# Why won't my image vertically align next to text?

Tags: html, css

Trying to get the Login text to have the user.png image but it's not showing.

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link text-black user-png" href="login.php">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-black" href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
```

CSS:

```
.user-png {
    
    background-image: url("user.png");
    height: 80%; 
   vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

[image: login]

Comment: What is your project folder structure?

Comment: I have the html in index.php so /index.php and the css is in /Style/index.css and I've linked them correctly because other changes show up.

Comment: What about the image file ?

Comment: Can u ss what's the result now?

Comment: It's a valid image, maybe css is wrong though.

Comment: @BariqDharmawan added it via edit.

Comment: Probably, you have the image in a separate folder outside the style folder. Try using  `background-image: url("../user.png");` or `background-image: url("../folder_name/user.png");`

Comment: @VictorSantizo I promise you this is not the case.

Comment: Instead of using `background-image`, use `background: url("user.png")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your login and sign up text inside a span.

also add display-inline to li.nav-tem style.

ref : [css align text in front of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646995/css-align-text-in-front-of-image)
https://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/

```css
li.nav-item{list-style:none;padding-left:20px;display: inline;}
li a img.user-png {
  width:85px;
  height:50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
 li a span.text {
  margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link text-black" href="login.php"><img src="user.png" class="user-png"> 
        <span class="text">Login</span>
    </a>
</li>


<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-black" href="signup.php">
        <span class="text">Sign Up</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Or if you want the link to be in front of the image do it like this

ref : [css align text in front of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646995/css-align-text-in-front-of-image)
https://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text

```css
/* manage list style*/
li.nav-item {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    display: inline;
}
/*add space to the left*/
li a.nav-link {
    padding-left:50px;
}

/* image size*/
li a img.user-png {
    width:85px;
    height:50px;
}

/*center image and text inside link a*/
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link text-black" href="login.php"><img src="user.png" class="user-png centered"> 
        <span class="centered">Login</span>
    </a>
</li>


<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-black" href="signup.php">
        <span class="centered">Sign Up</span>
    </a>
</li>
```